# getting a matrix into a sym variable

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to fit a function to my experimental data. The function is actually a summation of terms. I tried the symsum method to build my function.

z is a 155x1 matrix, Q is the value returned from lsqcurvefit, zo is a user defined input variable and k is the index of summation from 0 to 11.

```
syms z Q k r
Function=symsum( ((-Q)^k)*(1/(k+1)^1.5)/(1+z^2/r^2)^k,k)
```

I can't find method to use a matrix into sym. suggest me any alternate method.

Comment: Did you try not to create a `syms` variable z, but to use the numeric matrix directly? MATLAB will automatically do the conversion.

Comment: It worked. But the input should be a square matix